# Как удалить текст между заданным текстом?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Подскажите, как решить проблему на bash командой sed

есть файлик с содержанием:

```
бла бла бла
...
/*033cf*/

@include "\x2fhom\x65/mg\x6etep\x6co/m\x67nte\x70lo.\x72u/d\x6fcs/\x6dodu\x6ces/\x6dod_\x65xt_\x6denu\x6dati\x63/js\x2ffav\x69con\x5fd38\x3368.\x69co";

/*033cf*/
...
бла бла бла
```

Задача удалить все, начинающееся с `@include "\x2` и заканчивающиеся `;`

Comment: у вас в пример фрагменты `@include "\x2` и `;` находятся в одной строке, а вопрос — про **много**строчный текст. уточните, пожалуйста, что именно вы имеете в виду.

Comment: не дождавшись ответа на свой комментарий, но видя, что подошёл ответ, никакого отношения к **много**строчности не имеющий, удалил слово «многострочный» из заголовка вопроса.

Comment: Судя по всему, под "многострочностью" автор имел в виду наличие множества строк, которые необходимо заменить.

Comment: Прошу прошение! многострочность имелось введу во втором примере который я по рассеянности забыл опубликовать: $iCode="ffff"; а на второй строчке $iCode.="fffff";

Comment: `\x2f` скорее всего имеется в виду в шаблоне. */home/mgnteplo/mgnteplo.ru/docs/modules/mod_ext_menumatic/js/favicon_d38368.ico*

Answer (score 4):

Если не принципиально использование `sed`, предлагаю вариант с `grep`:

```
grep -v '^@include\ "\\x2.*;$' filename
```

`grep` покажет файл filename, а
`-v` удалит строки, начинающиеся с `@include "\x2` и заканчивающиеся `;`

Comment: Не принципиально, просто grep не смог грамотно написать! Большое СПАСИБО

Comment: Собственно и на `sed` просто: sed -i -e 's/^@include\ "\\x2.*;$//g' filename`

Answer (score 2):

удалить все строки, содержащие `фрагмент1`, а затем `фрагмент2`:

```
$ sed -i '/фрагмент1.*фрагмент2/d' файл
```

удалить все строки, *начинающиеся* с `фрагмент1` и *заканчивающиеся* на `фрагмент2` (`^` — привязка к началу строки, `$` — к концу):

```
$ sed -i '/^фрагмент1.*фрагмент2$/d' файл
```

удалить только части строк, начиная с `фрагмент1` и заканчивающиеся на `фрагмент2`:

```
$ sed -i 's/фрагмент1.*фрагмент2//' файл
```

---

если внутри фрагментов встречаются символы `/` или `\`, перед ними надо добавить символ `\`.

Comment: [code]sed -i 's/фрагмент1.*фрагмент2//' файл[/code]
А как можно сделать, чтоб удалялись только символы между фрагмент1 и фрагмент2, не удаляя фрагмент1 и фрагмент2?